# social sharing for posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I am trying to add social sharing links to my rails posts, without a gem. Here is my current code:

```
 <!-- Facebook -->
 <a onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<!-- Twitter -->

<a onclick="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<%= @post.title %> by @someuser - &amp;url=<%= url_for([@post, {only_path: false}]) %>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a>
```

Example Post: https://mirrorcommunications.herokuapp.com/blog/how-to-not-get-booed-at-your-next-presentation

Example source: view-source:https://mirrorcommunications.herokuapp.com/blog/how-to-not-get-booed-at-your-next-presentation

Facebook tries to open, then crashes and twitter gives me a page not found error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the rendered, final HTML that's being generated.

Comment: @ceejayoz added a link to a sample post for source.

Comment: So would this work? <%= url_for(["https://mirrorcommunications.herokuapp.com" + @post, {only_path: false}]) %>

Comment: Something like that, although you should probably figure out why `only_path: false` isn't working. I'm no RoR expert, but maybe it should be `:only_path: false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out:

Posts Controller:

```
# Social Sharing for Single Posts
def original_url
   base_url + original_fullpath
end
```

View:

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<a onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<%= request.original_url %>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<!-- Twitter -->

<a onclick="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=<%= @post.title %> by @someuser - &amp;url=<%= request.original_url %>', '_blank', 'width=800, height=500, top=200, left=300');void(0);"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></a>
```

Here is the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url

Answer (score 1):

Your `url_for` function is outputting URLs that won't work for Facebook/Twitter. The social networks don't know what to do with `/blog/how-to-not-get-booed-at-your-next-presentation` - they need the scheme and domain name, i.e. `https://mirrorcommunications.herokuapp.com/blog/how-to-not-get-booed-at-your-next-presentation`.